# Modificar um elemento do HTML ou uma função nativa do browser

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, protótipo

Galera, seguinte... O google chrome dá suporte ao elemento `<dialog>` e suas funções `showModal()` e `close()`. Porém, alguns navegadores não dão suporte. Fiz um script simples, que verifica o se o navegador é diferente do google chrome, e, se for, ele substitui as tags `<dialog>` por div's, com os ids, classes etc. A questão é: Existe algumas forma de substituir/reencrever as funções `showModal()` e `close()` para que execute a minha função? Ao invés da nativa?
Tentei com `HTMLElement.prototype.showModal` e nada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está querendo substituir a função apenas no Google Chrome e nos possíveis navegadores que dão suporte a esta implementação é exatamente como você escreveu, com uma pequena correção. Não é `HTMLElement`, mas sim `HTMLDialogElement`. Logo...

```
if (window.HTMLDialogElement) {

    HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModalOriginal = HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModal;

    HTMLDialogElement.prototype.showModal = function() {
        //Sua implementação aqui...
        alert('Substituição de showModal()');

        //Se quiser chamar a função nativa original...
        if (this.showModalOriginal instanceof Function) this.showModalOriginal();
    }

    HTMLDialogElement.prototype.closeOriginal = HTMLDialogElement.prototype.close;

    HTMLDialogElement.prototype.close= function() {
        //Sua implementação aqui...
        alert('Substituição de close()');

        //Se quiser chamar a função nativa original...
        if (this.closeOriginal instanceof Function) this.closeOriginal();
    }

}
```

**EDITADO1: Escrevi a verificação para o caso do navegador não implementar `HTMLDialogElement`.**

Comment: Vlwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww <3

Comment: Show de bola, Sergio. Precisei criar isso meio que rapidamente pra uma solucao na empresa.. Se quiser dar uma olhadinha como ficou o resultado final no meu [github](https://github.com/rpelizza/dialog)

Comment: Ficou maneiro, legal mesmo. Fiz um teste aqui e só notei que o z-index ficou abaixo num site qualquer que testei aqui. Coloquei em 2147483647 pra garantir e funcionou igualzinho no Microsoft Edge. Parabéns. Gostei.

Comment: Posta sua solução como resposta da sua própria pergunta aqui. Ficou maneiro.

Answer (score -1):

A solução com a ajuda do Sérgio Cabral!!!!

`(function() {

```
if (!(/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor))) {
    var dialogs = document.getElementsByTagName('dialog');
    var overlayModal = document.createElement('div');
    var randomId = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    overlayModal.style.cssText = 'z-index:2147483646 ;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height: 100%;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);display:none;'
    overlayModal.setAttribute('id', randomId);
    document.body.appendChild(overlayModal);

    for (var x = 0; x < dialogs.length; x++) {
        var elementClass = (dialogs[x].classList.length > 0) ? dialogs[x].className.split(' ') : null;
        var elementID = (dialogs[x].id.length  > 0) ? dialogs[x].id : null;
        var insideContent = dialogs[x].innerHTML;  
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        if (elementClass) newElement.classList = elementClass.join(' ');
        if (elementID) newElement.setAttribute('id', elementID);
        newElement.innerHTML += insideContent;
        newElement.style.cssText = 'display:none;position:fixed;z-index:2147483647;top:50%;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%);width:-webkit-fit-content;height:-webkit-fit-content;color:black;margin:auto;border-width:initial;border-style:solid;border-color:initial;-webkit-border-image:initial;-o-border-image:initial;border-image:initial;padding:1em;background:white;';
        document.body.appendChild(newElement);            
    }

    Array.prototype.slice.call(dialogs).forEach(function (item) {
        item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    });

    HTMLElement.prototype.showModal = function() {
        document.getElementById(randomId).style.display = 'block';
        this.style.display = 'block';
    }

    HTMLElement.prototype.close = function() {            
        document.getElementById(randomId).style.display = 'none';
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

}());`